# Datatables initialisation complete callback not triggered

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying to trigger an if statement in my initComplete function but it doesn't work. Why is this?
This is my code:

```js
 var dataTable = $('.datatable-column-search-inputs').DataTable({ 
initComplete: function () {
                   var myDate = new Date();
                   var n = myDate.getHours();
                 
                   if (n < 12) {
                     
                       dataTable.fnFilter(this.value, 'DESAYUNOS');
                       alert("LOGRO DESAYUNOS");
                   }
                   else  /* 12:00pm-5:59pm */
                       if (n >= 12 && n <= 17) {
                           dataTable.fnFilter(this.value, 'COMIDAS');
                           alert("LOGRO COMIDAS");
                       }
                       else  /* 6:00PM-12:00AM*/
                           if (n > 17 && n <= 24) {
                               $('#sel2').change(function () {
                                   dataTable.fnFilter(this.value, 'CENAS');
                                   alert("LOGRO CENAS");
                               });
                           }
                           else  /* the hour is not between 0 and 24, so something is wrong */ {
                               alert("I'm not sure what time it is!");
                           }

                   });
                  

               }
   });
```

HTML TABLE:

```html
  <table class='table datatable-column-search-inputs table-hover table-striped table-bordered'>

                                    <thead>

                                        <tr>

                                            <td class='thead_search'>Platillo</td>
                                            <td class='thead_select'>Pdv</td>
                                            <td class='thead_select'>Rid</td>
                                            <td>PV</td>
                                            <td>1</td>
                                            <td>2</td>
                                            <td>3</td>

                                            <td>Total</td>
                                            <td class='text-center'>Venta</td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th colspan="4" style="text-align:left">Total:</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>

                                </table>
```

i just added the HTML sintax of the table, the table is filled by an ajax call, it fills correctly but my IF statement on the initComplete: never sends the alert no matter what time is it none of the even the last else
Why doesn't the callback function get triggered?

Comment: Can you add the part of html containing the table?

Comment: y just added the table code, all the if, neighter of them sends the alert so that means neighter of them enters @NisseEngström

Comment: just a guess, but could you add an id to your table and initialise the datatables on the id?

Answer (score 0):

`fnFilter()` is API method of older jQuery DataTables 1.9 but variable `dataTable` is an instance of `DataTable()` which provides access to newer API only (1.10+).

Either replace  `DataTable()` with `dataTable()` or use newer API method [`search()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/search%28%29) instead of `fnFilter()`.

Also second argument to `fnFilter()` should be an integer (zero-based column index), see [older API reference](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref).

Comment: but the problem persist, nighter of the alerts inside the if triggers like if the if statements are ignored